# Where is Cicero after he is spared?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

It's said that if [Cicero](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Cicero) is spared in [The Cure for Madness](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Cure_for_Madness) quest, he remains in the Dawnstar sanctuary and can be later hired as a follower. Well I did just that and I can't find him anywhere. Where exactly is he? Does he disappear and only reappear after some other moment in the game?

Comment: he should be in the dawnstar sanctuary once you've finished the DB quests.

Comment: @spartacus, dawnstar sanctuary is kinda big, hence the question...

Comment: @spartacus, wait a moment, do you mean *all* DB quests?

Comment: You say you *just* did that - "that" being sparing him. Did he walk away and disappear or something when you didn't kill him, or was this actually a while ago and you've returned to the Sanctuary looking for him?

Comment: No, he was alive there on the floor and I walked away. I came back after talking to Astrid and he was no longer there.

Comment: you have to finish the main db quest i believe

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you spare Cicero in the quest *A Cure For Madness* then he will be available **later in the quest line** from the Dawnstar Sanctuary.  Specifically, he will appear when *Hail Sithis* has been completed **and the Dragonborn first leaves** the Sanctuary through the front door.

After some amusing dialogue, he will enter the sanctuary (assuming you don't take him on as a follower straight away) and can be found next to the Night Mother's coffin on the balcony near the stairs.  It's fairly gloomy in there even with the furnishings purchased so a detect life spell may help until you get used to where he will be.

Comment: +1 that's pretty much from what I remember.  You need to finish the main DB quest before he becomes available.

Answer (score 1):

When you collect the money for killing the emperor Nasir will send you to delvin. As leaving the sanctuary, through the door, not the secret entrance, he will appear. After some dialogue you can recruit him as a follower. If not he stays near the night mother in the santurary. Hope this helps!

Comment: Welcome to Gaming SE. While your answer isn't bad, it contains no new information compared to the currently accepted answer (which was posted nearly two years ago!). If you have any new/additional information to add, please edit your answer to reflect this.

Answer (score -3):

From the [Elderscrolls wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Cicero)

> If the Dragonborn chose to spare his life, Cicero is found upon exiting the Dawnstar Sanctuary after the quest where he becomes a possible follower. Cicero is flagged as essential before "The Cure for Madness". If he is spared, he becomes essential again, making him unable to be killed.

Comment: Doesn't answer ***where***

Comment: Technically it does, "is found upon exiting the Dawnstar Sanctuary", just doesn't say where he goes after that to be permanently.